# Why does my VBA function not evaluate the source cell that returns a HYPERLINK based on an IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a cell with an IF function which either returns an empty value, or a hyperlink, based on whether another cell is empty or not

```
=IF($R7="","",HYPERLINK(CONCAT('Global Values'!$B$1,$R7),"LINK"))
```

In VBA I am trying to get the Address property of my hyperlink using a custom function GetURL()

```
Function GetURL(rng As Range) As String
   On Error Resume Next
   GetURL = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

The problem is that I get nothing instead of the Address for the eventual URL equated from my IF function

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `HYPERLINK` function does **NOT** add the `.Hyperlinks` collection to the `Range` object.  See:

[VBA to open Excel hyperlink does not work when hyperlink generated with a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422003/vba-to-open-excel-hyperlink-does-not-work-when-hyperlink-generated-with-a-formul)

So you can either

- examine the `.Value` property of the cell, or
- add a hyperlink to the cell

Try one of the variants of the code below:

```
Function GetURL(rng As Range) As String
   'GetURL = rng.Value

'OR

    With rng
        If .Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then
            .Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=.Item(1), Address:=.Value, TextToDisplay:=.Value
        End If

        GetURL = .Hyperlinks(1).Address

    End With
End Function
```

***If necessary, you can add some testing to ensure that `.Value` evaluates to a hyperlink.  Perhaps ensure that the `HYPERLINK` function is found in the `.Formula` property***